# Antenna for qrp pixie 2

Tags: transceiver, ham-radio

I recently set up a qrp pixie 2  transceiver i purchased from Aliexpress.I want to use it for sending morse code,and  listening to the shortwave transmissions.and i want to learn more about it.so i need to set up and antenna for it, i need  help with what kind of antenna i should use, and how can i make it.
This is the qrp pixie kit I'm talking about:

https://m.aliexpress.com/s/item/32671273995.html?spm=a2g0n.search-cache.0.0.7dc3a52561enmM#autostay

Comment: Yes of course its the qrp pixie transciever I'm talking about

Comment: Oh sorry, not this one, i meant the one without the led and speaker

Comment: Its the "qrp pixie 2 40 meter CW transciever"

Comment: Since the transciever operates on 7 MHz (40 Metre Amateur band), you require an antenna designed for that frequency.

Answer (score 5):

You do not say where you are.

The radio you reference requires you to hold an Amateur Radio operator's license.  If you are in the United States, you need an Extra Class license (the highest), because the operating frequency is in the Extra Class sub-band of the 40 meter ham band.  If you are somewhere else, check the local laws.  (If you are in Thailand, check with the Radio Amateur Society of Thailand.  I've been to one of their meetings. 
 They're good people and they can and will help you.)

You'll need an antenna designed for the 7 MHz (40 meter) band.  There are LOTS of books out there that will tell you how to cut a simple dipole or inverted-V antenna.